# laravel dompdf error unlink(.png): No such file or directory image

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I had an error on the production server when I was about to print the pdf the error was unlink(.png): No such file or directory. when on the local server there were no problems at all, I hosted my Laravel on the company's private production server using the iis manager. sorry my english is bad because i use google translate

get image in dompdf like this

```
 public function printdetail($id){
        $pathfile = public_path('app-assets/images/icons/INDOPRIMA.jpg');
        $opnumber = str_replace('_','/',$id);

        $customPaper;
        $datahdr = db::connection('sqlsrv5')->table('trs_op_Hdr')->where('OP_Number',$opnumber)->first();
     
        $datadtl = db::connection('sqlsrv5')->table('trs_op_Dtl')
        ->selectRaw("trs_op_Dtl.*,ms.Mes_Name")
        ->leftJoin('Mst_Inv as inv','trs_op_Dtl.Inv_Code','inv.Inv_Code')
        ->leftJoin('Mst_Meas as ms','inv.Inv_Unit1','ms.Mes_Code')
        ->where('trs_op_Dtl.OP_Number',$datahdr->OP_Number)->get();

        $customPaper = (count($datadtl)<2)? array(0,0,907.086,560):array(0,0,907.086,1040);
        $matauang = db::connection('sqlsrv5')->table('Mst_Cur_Hdr')->get();
        $supplier = db::connection('sqlsrv5')->table('Mst_Supp')->select('Sup_Name','Sup_Address','Sup_City')->where('Sup_Code',$datahdr->Sup_Code)->first();
        
        $pdf = PDF::loadview('purchasing.transaction.pcin_tra_purchase_order.report',compact('datahdr','datadtl','matauang','supplier','pathfile'));
        $pdf->setPaper($customPaper, 'portrait');
        return $pdf->stream();
    }
```

on blade

```
  <img  style="display:inline-block;" src="{{$pathfile}}"  alt="avatar" height="35" width="35" />
```

i tested on localserver in my laptop not error but when access my project in production server i got error unlink(.png): No such file or directory

Comment: Not seeing code that seems relevant to your question. Assume it is tied to path, absolute/relative. But not seeing really where the full path and filename is derived.

Comment: Maybe search your other code for the unlink() function, since that's what's throwing the error. It looks like maybe a variable that's supposed to have the filename in it is empty at some point in some code. You just have to find it :/